# pyautogui does not have screenshot function error

Tags: python, pyautogui

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMl1V.png)
[screenshot function not in functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjdRB.png)
The function screenshot does not work for me.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the library's pyautgui and pillow, however it's still raising the same error. I have also tried to date my library's and this did not fix the issue for me.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us the exact code you are running and also copy and paste the error message you are getting? What version of Python and what operating system are you on? Also run `import pyautogui;print(pyautogui.__version__)` and tell us what exact version of PyAutoGUI you're using.